# Can I automatically create a passworded user with pw adduser on freebsd?

Tags: bash, scripting, freebsd, automation, useradd

Can I automatically create a passworded user with pw adduser on freebsd?

```
 pw useradd [name] [switches]
        -V etcdir      alternate /etc location
        -C config      configuration file
        -q             quiet operation
  Adding users:
        -n name        login name
        -u uid         user id
        -c comment     user name/comment
        -d directory   home directory
        -e date        account expiry date
        -p date        password expiry date
        -g grp         initial group
        -G grp1,grp2   additional groups
        -m [ -k dir ]  create and set up home
        -M mode        home directory permissions
        -s shell       name of login shell
        -o             duplicate uid ok
        -L class       user class
        -h fd          read password on fd
        -H fd          read encrypted password on fd
        -Y             update NIS maps
        -N             no update
  Setting defaults:
        -V etcdir      alternate /etc location
        -D             set user defaults
        -b dir         default home root dir
        -e period      default expiry period
        -p period      default password change period
        -g group       default group
        -G grp1,grp2   additional groups
        -L class       default user class
        -k dir         default home skeleton
        -M mode        home directory permissions
        -u min,max     set min,max uids
        -i min,max     set min,max gids
        -w method      set default password method
        -s shell       default shell
        -y path        set NIS passwd file path
```

According to this, I can. But I am not sure how... It seems I need to use a file descriptor but I've not been able to see any example of how to do this. I have a bash script which needs to automatically do this with no user input...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using a file descriptor:

```
echo password | pw useradd -h 0 user1
```

Every Unix process typically has three standard file descriptors:

- `stdin` (0)
- `stdout` (1)
- `stderr` (2)

In this case, we're telling `pw` to read input from fd 0, aka `stdin`.  You may want to review the `bash` man page, which has all sorts of examples of fancy things you can do with file descriptors and redirection.

Note that there are some security issues with this example -- anyone running the `ps` command at the right time would be able to see the argument to the `echo` command.  This may or may not be a concern in your environment.  You could do this instead:

```
pw useradd -h 0 user1 <<EOP
password
EOP
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that your FreeBSD system has the following installed

bash (pkg_add -r bash)
expect (pkg_add -r expect)

Below is a script that will auto generate random passwords and automatically apply it to the root account.  You can make this a startup script.  I would first make the following directories.

1. From root directory not root's home mkdir .script
2. Have a normal user account
3. mkdir /var/log/.rec
4. chown normaluser:normaluser /var/log/.rec
5. place the passgen.sh script in to .script that is located in the root file structure
6. chmod 777 passgen.sh

   ## !/usr/local/bin/bash

   PASSGEN=`head -c 10 /dev/random | uuencode -m - | tr -d '\n' | cut -c 19-32`

> echo $PASSGEN > /var/log/.rec/encrypted
>
> chown someuser:someuser /var/log/.rec/encrypted
>
> chmod 666 /var/log/.rec/encrypted
>
> ## Encryption is obfuscation
>
> LOG=root
>
> PASS=$PASSGEN
>
> expect << EOF
>
> spawn passwd $LOG
>
> expect "New Password:"
>
> send "${PASS}\r"
>
> expect "Retype New Password:"
>
> send "${PASS}\r"
>
> expect eof;
>
> EOF

now add this to your startup rc.local / rc.d / rc.conf depending on your version of BSD.

Hope this helps someone out there, looks like this editor is filter some hashes and half quotes.

Thank You
Sean Hulbert